# Not able to query through the list in firebase using angularfire2

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to get the list of users where text=Groomers from firebase database
I am getting firebase warning about .indexOn, but not getting the list of users.
Below is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
selector: 'app-animal-services',
templateUrl: './animal-services.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./animal-services.component.css']
})
export class AnimalServicesComponent implements OnInit {

users: Observable<any[]>;

constructor(public _firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db:  AngularFireDatabase, private router: Router) {

 this.users = db.list('/professionals', ref => ref.orderByChild('text').equalTo("Groomers")).valueChanges();


}

ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

Below is the image of my database:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`orderByChild("text")` should be `orderByChild("qualification")`

Comment: Still not getting the list after using orderByChild("qualification ") .

Answer (score 0):

Phew! I figured out my way by changing the database in the following way:

Below is the image of my [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a7BN.png):